# Xcode 5 how to jump to .m file not .h or definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode 5. However sometime when I used cmd+click to check the definition, I also wanna know how the code look like.

For example, when I cmd+click the instance method of the array name lastObject, the screen will jump to the code -(id)lastObject; under NSArray.h

The problem is I want to see the code in NSArray.m not .h file.
Is there any way to go or jump to implementation file?

Thanks!!

Comment: The .m files are hidden for cocoa framework objects. You can't see `NSArray.m`

Comment: You may be interested in Apple's open source page, which has the implementations for Core Foundation, including CFArray: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.19/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .m file is private. You can not see any code in .m files created by Apple. If its your own code then it will go to the appropriate implementation of the method you click.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Cocoa frameworks are encapsulated inside XCode so you can't access the *.m files of Foundation objects. However, you can `option+click` on Cocoa methods to quickly open up Apple's documentation where all the information about the method's usage should be present.